# How to set docklayoutpanel borderwidth in gwt

Tags: java, css, gwt

Heres my code snippet, whats wrong?

mydocklayoutpanle.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("borderWidth", "4");

All i need is to show the borders. Any suggestion would  help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dockPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border","black solid 4px");